# Rails - unique template for multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For an application, I need several controllers having more or less the same behavior (with a few particularities for each).
So basically, I have something like that:

```
# controllers/main.rb
MainController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    ...
  end

  def create
    ...
  end

  def destroy
    ...
  end
end

# controllers/first.rb
FirstController < MainController
  helper_method :custom_stuff_one

  private
  def custom_stuff_one
    'bli'
  end
end

# controllers/second.rb
SecondController < MainController
  helper_method :custom_stuff_two

  private
  def custom_stuff_two
    'bla'
  end
end

# routes.rb
resources :first, :only => [:show, :create, :destroy]
resources :second, :only => [:show, :create, :destroy]
```

That works fine, but I wasn't able to have the same simplicity for templates. What I'd like would be something simple as:

```
# views/main/show.html.erb
<html>
  <body>
    Here the stuff in common for all controllers ...
  </body>
</html>

# views/first/show.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('my_css_only_for_first') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag(custom_stuff_one) %>

# views/second/show.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('another/css/file') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag(custom_stuff_two) %>
```

And of course, when accessing /first/1 the template rendered is "views/main/show.html.erb" (and the include tags from "views/first/show.html.erb").

I'm getting a bit lost with the yield, layouts etc... (and I'm also wondering if I'm not doing something wrong with controller inheritance too ...)

Any ideas ?

Note: we're using Rails 3.2.17, Ruby 2.1.1

Cheers,
Vincent

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong ? What would you like to do exactly? You said that when you access /first/1, the main template is rendered?

Comment: Yes that's the idea: rendering the main template but also add the custom tags from "views/first/show.html.erb". There will only be extra tags in head by the way, nothing in the body.

Comment: Ok I understand, I'm going to try to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the controller you already have, if you query /first/1, you will render /first/show and will not consider the main/show. What you want to use is a layout, a layout is a piece of HTML code that is reusable between controllers.

You should then create a file called layouts/layout_name.html.erb :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <%= yield :head %>
  <head>
  <body>
    <%=yield%>
  </body>
</html>
```

On your controllers, add

```
# controllers/first.rb
FirstController < MainController
  helper_method :custom_stuff_one
  layout :layout_name
  ...
end
```

And on your views
for first :

```
<%=content_for :head do%>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag('my_css_only_for_first') %> #This will display in the head
<%end%>

<div>FOO</div> #This will display in the body
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a layout with a custom yield line in the head section:

```
yield :head
```

Then you can put something there from your individual views. Eg from your show.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :head do
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('another/css/file') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag(custom_stuff_two) %>
<% end %>
```

See more info [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for)